# Conditional expression for a specific column in a list of data frames in R

Tags: r, list

Sorry if the title is confusing.

I have a list of data frames combined into temp.list. I want to raise each row of a specific column based on the value in vec. For example, vec has the values 2, 0, and 3. I want to do: X2^2, log(X2), X2^3. So do log(X2) if the value in vec==0. The last three lines of code is where I have an issue.

```
M1 <- data.frame(matrix(1:4, nrow = 2, ncol = 2))
M2 <- data.frame(matrix(1:9, nrow = 3, ncol = 3))
M3 <- data.frame(matrix(1:4, nrow = 2, ncol = 2))

mlist <- list(M1, M2, M3)
temp.list <-mlist
vec <- c(2,0,3)
```

The code below works! But I don't want to raise X2^0.

```
for(i in 1:length(vec)){
  temp.list[[i]]$X2 <- temp.list[[i]]$X2^vec[[i]]
}
```

The code below replaces all rows of X2 by the first value calculated in X2.

```
for(i in 1:length(vec)){
  temp.list[[i]]$X2 <- ifelse(vec[[i]]==0,log(temp.list[[i]]$X2),temp.list[[i]]$X2^vec[[i]]
}
```

Any other ways of doing this would also be much appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps, instead of `vec`, you could define your functions in a list and call them as needed. E.g. `funs = list(function(x) x ^ 2, function(x) log(x), function(x) x ^ 3)`; `for(i in 1:length(funs)) print(funs[[i]](temp.list[[i]]$X2))`.

Comment: That would work for the temp problem. Unfortunately, the actual dataset I have is quite large. There are 114 data frames in the list, so having the ifelse conditional, or some other type of conditional, seems mandatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use this:

```
for(i in 1:length(vec)){
  temp.list[[i]]$X2 <- if(vec[[i]]==0) log(temp.list[[i]]$X2) 
                           else temp.list[[i]]$X2^vec[[i]]
}
temp.list
# [[1]]
#   X1 X2
# 1  1  9
# 2  2 16

# [[2]]
#   X1       X2 X3
# 1  1 1.386294  7
# 2  2 1.609438  8
# 3  3 1.791759  9

# [[3]]
#   X1 X2
# 1  1 27
# 2  2 64
```

The problem is with the `ifelse(...)` statement, which returns a vector of the same length as the condition (e.g., 1 in your case). The `if (...) ... else ...` statement evaluates the expression and executes whichever block of code is appropriate.